# Ballerina echoservice example throws an error

Tags: wso2, ballerina, ballerina-composer

I've just installed **Ballerina** version **0.8.0** on **Windows**. Following the tutorial I tried the **echoservice** example.
Launching the command from the \ballerina-0.8.0\samples\echoService folder

```
ballerina run service echoService.bal
```

I received this response

```
error in ballerina program: value
     at echo(echoService.bal:6)
     at echo(echoService.bal:3)
```

where the line 6 is

```
resource echo (message m) {
```

The example **helloworldservice** runs propertly.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Gianni

UPDATED 2017-02-26:
This is the code I'm executing from ballerina-0.8.0/samples/echoService folder. I'm running it from Git Bash, but it's the same from Command Prompt.

```
import ballerina.net.http;
@http:BasePath ("/echo")
service echo {

    @http:POST
    resource echo (message m) {
        http:convertToResponse(m);
        reply m;

    }

}
```

I launch this command

```
../../bin/ballerina.bat run service echoService.bal
```

The console shows the same error.

I'm calling the service using Fiddler...

```
POST http://localhost:9090/echo HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:9090
Content-Length: 3

sss
```

...and I receive this response

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 33
Content-Type: text/plain

error in ballerina program: value
```

Comment: Can you check compare the echoService with the original pack?

Comment: I'm executing the original sample pack echoservice bal file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to invoke HTTP POST method without Content-Type. Can you check setting "Content-Type" header to "application/json"

Answer (score 1):

You should post your entire program.  I was able to successfully get it to run as shown on the ballerinalang.org home page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the echo sample which worked for me.

```
import ballerina.net.http;
@http:BasePath("/echo")
service echo {
    @http:POST
    resource echo(message m) {
        http:convertToResponse(m);
        reply m;    
    }
}
```

You can run it by

> ballerina run service path/to/echo.bal

from the bin directory, or can do the same via ballerina composer as well.

Comment: I tried to remove the new lines after `service echo {` and after the second curly bracket, but the result is the same

Comment: Windows 10, Ballerina 0.8, x64.
Do you need other config info?

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce this issue. I used Advanced REST client app in Chrome. I could resolve the error when I set the Content-Type header as follows.

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded